# Why does adding the ::before or ::after pseudo selectors cause the base element to disappear during animation?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I’m experimenting with flat button design and tried to put an animation on the whole class to enlarge on `:hover`. After I added the `:after` pseudo-element, my base class would disappear behind the `:after` when it animates. I tried putting `z-index:-1;` on the `:hover:after` pseudo-element, but it doesn’t bring it forward. I’ve changed the opacity of the `:after` element as a proof to see that it goes behind.

How can I ensure that the base element is on top? I can change the background-color to 'none', but what if I require it to be filled?

In addition, how do I refer to only the base element? When I do `class:hover`, it refers to the entire object, including both the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

#### HTML:

```
<div id='wrap'>
  <button class='a'>Test</button>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#wrap{
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}
.a{
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.a:after{
  border-radius: inherit;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 112px;
  width: 112px;
  border: 4px red solid;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-color: white;
}
.a:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}
.a:hover:after{
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/pthieu/pen/LJicp).

Comment: Found the answer sort of: Adding ::before or ::after pseudo-classes will place content within the tag, so they will always be above your base element. Adding in transition effects have to be tinkered tightly  to make sure the layering stays consistently throughout the entire animation. I don't really know how to do it properly but I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for giving your partial answer in a comment. If you find a full answer, please feel free to share it here. Answering your own questions on Stack Overflow is encouraged as a way to share knowledge.